# NFS shared folder is mounted with "nobody" permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, nfs

With a server with Scientific Linux 6.4 and a client with Scientific Linux 7, the server has the following `/etc/export` definition

`/home/control/nfs02    *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)`

On the client we have this in `/etc/fstab`

`SERVER_IP:/home/control/nfs02    /home/control/nfs    nfs    defaults    0 0`

The folder gets mounted but with `nobody:nobody` user and group permissions recursively.

What I tried:

1. I tried working with different `fstab` options like this: `rw,sync,nosuid,users` and `defaults`
2. In the client's `/etc/idmap.conf`, I tried setting static translation and added a mapping like this: `control@IP = control`.
3. I enabled NFS ID mapping through `/sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping` (According to a Server Fault SE question I lost) and then cleared the ID mapping cache `nfsidmap -c` with restarting the `rpcidmapd` service.

I eventually ended up modifying the Nobody group and user in `/etc/idmap.conf` on the client both to `control` which I don't think it is the ideal case. All clients will mount the same share having the same user name and group, an `fstab` entry should be sufficient for mounting with respect to the user. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: @Q23 The most important info not forgotten xD, question updated.

Comment: Are you sure you are using NFSv4? Is the `idmapd`running? Did you modify `idmapd.conf` also on the server? See e.g. http://www.unix-info.org/nfsV4_howto_.txt

Comment: @ridgy Yes. All of this did not work. I started to suspect that the issue is somehow because of the domain. The client is on a LAN with a DHCP that distributes the hostname something like `company.local` and can be found using `dnsdomainname` command, the server has static IP configurations with DNS entries as IP addresses. `domainname` and `dnsdomainname` returns nothing on the server.

Comment: As the text in the link says, in 2.) on server and client you should have the same domain.